# in case of an f:viewParam bound to a converter, why do we need the Converter#getAsString

Tags: jsf, converters, viewparams

Say I have the following **f:viewParam** definition:

```
<f:metadata>
    <f:viewParam name="cust-id" value="#{CustomerCEVController.customer}" 
        converter="#{customerConverter}" converterMessage="Unknown customer, please use a link from within the system."
        required="true" requiredMessage="cust-id f:viewParam not present"
    />
</f:metadata>
```

I navigate to the intended page with a "?cust-id=2342" parameter in the URL and so the role of the **getAsObject** method in the converter is to obviously instantiate the Customer field in the backing bean (e.g. by doing a DB query based on the cust-id value).
What's not very clear to me is why we need the **getAsString** method and how it is employed. This is not a question about the role of the **getAsString** in converters in the usual case, i.e. in the binding between the *.xhtml* view UI elements and the backing bean where their role is straightforward. I 've also read [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6377798/what-can-fmetadata-and-fviewparam-be-used-for) that we can treat the **f:viewParam** as a UI input element for GET parameters but the role of the converter in the opposite direction doesn't make sense to me.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `getAsString()` is indeed not used in case of `<f:viewParam>`, but an existing converter can be **reused** for other components where `getAsString()` is really been used.

E.g.

```
<h:outputText value="#{CustomerCEVController.customer}" converter="#{customerConverter}" />
```

or

```
<h:selectOneMenu value="#{CustomerCEVController.customer}" converter="#{customerConverter}">
    <f:selectItems value="#{data.customers}" />
</h:selectOneMenu>
```

It's up to you whether to implement `getAsString()` as per [its contract](http://docs.oracle.com/javaee/6/api/javax/faces/convert/Converter.html#getAsString%28javax.faces.context.FacesContext,%20javax.faces.component.UIComponent,%20java.lang.Object%29) or not. If you don't, then your converter would not be reuseable for other components at all.

Comment: Strangely using Mojarra 2.1.23 a converter binded to a `<f:viewParam>` on side load calls 5 times `getAsString`. Saw this behavior when I tried to throw an `UnsupportedOperationException` exception in the mentioned method.